# D3 v4 Line Chart: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to create a line graph using d3, but using javascript object instead of a tsv like the bl.ocks example. However, no matter how I try to parse the time data (written as years e.g. "2003"), I receive the error:

`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"`

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x( parseTime(d.year)); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.locations); });


  x.domain(d3.extent(myData, function(d) { return  parseTime(d.year); }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(myData, function(d) { return d.locations; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(myData)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
```

The data comes from a spreadsheet that is then converted into a javascript object.

```
myData=[{"year":"2000","locations":1286.0,"}]
```

I've tried changing `%Y` to `%y` and I've tried formatting the year column in the spreadsheet so it results in `2000.0` and `01/01/2000` instead of a string.

```
myData=[{"year":2000.0,"locations":1286.0,"}]
```

I've also used `new Date()` instead of `parseTime`, but I don't know what the error message is trying to show

Comment: This set up should work `var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");` then
`console.log(parseTime(2000));` If not, I'd try logging d.year and d.locations to see if there is any garbage in the data.

Comment: Thank you. Should the data "year" be a string or number? And if number should it be a float (2000.0) or integer (2000). If your solution is correct I think the spreadsheet formatting is where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't matter as long as it's not a string float like `"2000.0"`. Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXGvjO?editors=1111) I tested with

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working. xScale now returning NaN

Comment: What happens when you change the `rangeRound` to just `range` for both x and y scales?